# Retrieving selected values from Randomly created dynamic RadioButtonList from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist, dynamic-controls

I am trying to make a questionaire and get the selected value of radiobuttonlist of a question from database. The radiobuttonlist was generated dynamically in code behind. The Question and the list item for Radiobuttonlist was displayed randomly.

What I am trying to do is compare the answer from the user with the answerkey from DB when button click. So, I need to take the radiobuttonlist.selected value.

When trying to retrieve the selected value, I received null value. I think it was due to the question and radiobuttonlist was displayed randomly, so the id to call it back was changed. Is there any way on how to take the selected value of it?

Here is my code so far,

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    LoadControls2()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadControls2()
    keyList = New ArrayList
    Dim dtTable As DataTable
    'Select and randomize the Question taken from DB
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select TOP 3 [Question], [Choice], [Answer] from tbl_Question ORDER BY NEWID()")
    dtTable = ExecuteQuery(cmd, "SELECT")
    lblMsg.Text = strMsg
    For i As Integer = 0 To dtTable.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim tmpRBL As Object = New RadioButtonList
        Dim tmpLBL As Object = New Label

        tmpLBL.ID = "Label" & i
        tmpLBL.Text = i + 1 & ". " & dtTable.Rows(i)(0).ToString()
        tmpLBL.CssClass = "forLabel"

        tmpRBL.ID = i & "rbl"
        tmpRBL.CssClass = "forRadio"

        'Radnom the multiple choice
        Dim temp() As String = dtTable.Rows(i)(1).ToString().Split(New Char() {";"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim rnd As New System.Random
        Dim MyRandomArray = temp.OrderBy(Function() rnd.Next)
        For x As Integer = 0 To MyRandomArray.Count - 1
            Dim tmpItem As Object = New ListItem(MyRandomArray(x))
            tmpRBL.Items.Add(tmpItem)
        Next

        tmpRBL.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Flow
        tmpRBL.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tmpLBL)
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tmpRBL)
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</br>"))

        keyList.Add(dtTable.Rows(i)(2).ToString())
    Next
    'Store the answer Key
    Session("ArrayKey") = keyList

End Sub
```

Got null in this part,

```
Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim majstor_rbl(3) As String
    Dim arrayKey As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    arrayKey = Session("ArrayKey")

    For i As Integer = 0 To 2
        RadioButtonList = TryCast(PlaceHolder1.FindControl(i & "rbl"), RadioButtonList)
        majstor_rbl(i) = RadioButtonList.SelectedValue 'got null in here

    Next

End Sub
```

When I tried to take the `Radiobuttolist.SelectedValue` from the user, I always got `null` except for the question and radiobuttonlist that appeared before.
Any suggestion what I should do?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to access value using `Request.Form()`,

```
Request.Form(RadioButtonList.UniqueID)
```

Comment: did you mean something like txt = Request.Form("RadioButtonList") when calling the selectedvalue? I have tried it but it still produce null

Comment: Yes, actually dynamically created control's viewstate does not maintain. So we need to access them from Request object.

Comment: But, it still retrieved null,

Comment: Did you selected any value?

Comment: yes, already. I change the above code majstor_rbl(i) = RadioButtonList.SelectedValue  --> majstor_rb(i) = request.form("radiobuttonlist")

Comment: still error, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."... I think the id got replace when postback just like the object....

Comment: You should get unique id of radio button list. So it should not gives an error.

Comment: I think, I am going to create two procedure for postback and not postback... 
thanks for your help...